# Why not use addon-domain.com pointing at domain.com.au/public_html instead of htaccess 301 redirect to domain.com.au?

Tags: seo, add-on-domain

I am experimenting with Addon domains.

I understand that normally one sets up a 301 redirect when pointing, for example, domain.com at domain.com.au (where domain.com.au is to become the new primary domain with a new website on it)

The old domain.com has a wix website that we are throwing out and moving everthing to a new hosting service on a Centos Web Panel VPS i control.

I was considering;

setting up two copies of the website (ie domain.com and domain.com.au) and hosting them on separate accounts, OR

Setup the new website on domain.com.au and create an addon for domain.com with redirects using htaccess.

I am using Centos-web Panel. I note that when i create the Addon domain, i have the option to set its home directory.

So if i set home directory for the addon domain to domain.com.au/public_html (where the new wordpress website for domain.com.au resides) is that good enough for SEO rankings?

Essentially, if i now type in domain.com, it loads domain.com.au. Is that going to work, or does google penalise a change from .com to .com.au even though the "domain name" is the same?

What negatives and other issues can i expect from doing this?

Comment: Where is your site targeted?  Is it just for users from Australia or are you hoping for a worldwide audience?   If you are hoping for worldwide, why do you have a .au domain?

Comment: "...is that good enough for SEO rankings?" - If you don't use a 301 redirect then you have two websites hosting the same content. (?)

Comment: Hi, the owner has a small removalist business which only does local work to his area mostly...so only Australia at this point in time. He originally did a DIY setup with a .com and a wix website. This came about because competitors are taking business from him because of better websites, better seo etc. I just dont want to cause him to loose what little google rankings he has when we do away with the wix website (it will become a wordpress site on his .com or a redirect to .com.au)